# I can able to ping my server with IP but not by computer name

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, ip

I am using windows 2008 server. Once in a day my server stops responding [I can ping my server by IP not by computer name] to my Windows XP client but where i have Widnows 7 i can work as usual. I am am using server in workgroup.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

What type of internal name resolution mechanism are you using? Do you have an internal DNS server that all of the computers are configured to use? If not, then I'd say that's your problem. You can either set up an internal DNS server or use the hosts file on each computer.

Comment: Now I can ping my server name & IP both but I cannot conect to the server by \\servername. My compuyter gets hang and after I restart my server the problem is resolved. HELP!!

Answer (score 0):

You can hard code the IP address into the hosts file on the windows host.  You can locate this file in the following location. This will eliminate the DNS lookup if DNS is causing your issue.

C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
e.g.
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

127.0.0.1       localhost

192.168.1.10 servername
```

Comment: Now I can ping my server name & IP both but I cannot conect to the server by \\servername. My compuyter gets hang and after I restart my server the problem is resolved. HELP!!